# Error when click on Add in RadGrid: Failed to enable constraints. 1 or more rows contain values violating constraints

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, tableadapter

There were many similar questions in StackOverFlow but none gave an answer..
when I click on "Add New" button of RadGrid, I get below error:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values
>   violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

**HTML code:**

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="BURelationship" UniqueName="BURelationship" HeaderText="Relationship" SortExpression="BURelationship">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblRelationship" Text='<%# Eval("BURelationship") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRelationship" runat="server" Width="150" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

**C# code:**

```
public DataTable _dtBU;

protected void rgBU_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
        {
            _dtBU = SDM.BU.GetBU();

            GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

            DropDownList rlist = item.FindControl("ddlRelationship") as DropDownList;
            rlist.DataTextField = "RName";              
            rlist.DataValueField = "RID";
            rlist.DataSource = SDM.BU.GetAllRelationship();
            rlist.DataBind();

            foreach (DataRow dr in _dtBU.Rows)
            {
                if (dr["ID"].ToString() == item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString())
                {                        
                    rlist.SelectedValue = dr["BURelationship"].ToString();    
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {           
    }
}

protected void rgBU_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
     _dtBU = SDM.BU.GetBU();
     rgBU.DataSource = _dtBU;
}
```

**SDM.BU class file code (BLL):**

```
    #region GET
    public SDMDAL.SDM_Master_BUDataTable GetBU()
    {
        return Adapter.GetBU();
    }

    public DataTable GetAllRelationship()
    {
        DataTable dt = Adapter.GetRelationship();
        return dt;
    }        
    #endregion
```

**Database Table Structure:**

[image]

In this Table, RfoStatusID is the foreign Key.

**DataSet Table Adapter Structure: (DLL)**

[image]

**Stored Procedure to bind the DropDownList is**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SDM_Select_Relationship]
    AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT distinct [RID], [RName] 
    FROM [SDM_DB].[dbo].[SDM_Master_Relationship](NOLOCK)
    ORDER BY [RID] 
END
```

Please let me know the cause of this error and how to resolve it ? I am unable to understand why this error is coming. Whenever I click on Add New button of RadGrid, Add panel opens with this Logging Exception. Please let me know What is wrong in my code ? 
  **NOTE:** I am very new in Table Adapter method and 1st time using it. 
 Please reply

I even tried to follow this link: [ASP.NET dataset getdataBy Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014365/asp-net-dataset-getdataby-failed-to-enable-constraints-one-or-more-rows-contain)
but still this error remains the same. Please someone help me to resolve it.

Comment: Just a guess... 

rlist.SelectedValue = dr[7].ToString();   causes this error.. check if you have 8 items inside the list..

Comment: @Chris: thank you for the reply. Yes the `DataRow dr` has 9 items in it i.e., 0 to 9. What shall I change in my code ? Please reply

Comment: Did you check the number of rows present in the **_dtBU**?

Comment: @SankarRaj: Yes the `DataTable _dtBU` has multiple records in it. This error occurs when I click on AddNew button of RadGrid and Add records panel comes.

Comment: Please anyone reply to this issue. I am stuck in this since long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new TableAdapter for binding the DropDownList and its working fine now. Previously I was using 1 TableAdapter to bind RadGrid as well as this DropDownList so only it was showing error.